# To store DateTime value into php and mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am working on how to put Date value into my PHP/MySQL using android's date picker. 
I want to make a Sharing Parking lot application that owner can register one's parking place with its information like operating time. Then user can use it with choosing the beginning and ending points.
I searched a lot but need more specific information.
How can I save operating time slot into PHP/MySQL?

The following is my android java code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.avtivity_date_time);

    mText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    mPickDate1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate1);
    mPickTime1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime1);

    mText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    mPickDate2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate2);
    mPickTime2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime2);

    mPickDate1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_1);
        }
    });

    mPickDate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_2);
        }
    });

    mPickTime1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID_1);
        }
    });

    mPickTime2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID_2);
        }
    });

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth1 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mHour1 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute1 = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    mYear2 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth2 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay2 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mHour2 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute2 = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    updateDisplay();
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    mText1.setText(String.format("시작 : %d년 %d월 %d일 %d시 %d분", mYear1, mMonth1 + 1, mDay1, mHour1, mMinute1));
    mText2.setText(String.format("종료 : %d년 %d월 %d일 %d시 %d분", mYear2, mMonth2 + 1, mDay2, mHour2, mMinute2));
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener1 =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear1 = year;
                mMonth1 = monthOfYear;
                mDay1 = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener2 =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear2 = year;
                mMonth2 = monthOfYear;
                mDay2 = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener1 =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mHour1 = hourOfDay;
                mMinute1 = minute;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener2 =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mHour2 = hourOfDay;
                mMinute2 = minute;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID_1:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener1, mYear1, mMonth1, mDay1);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID_1:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener1, mHour1, mMinute1, false);

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID_2:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener2, mYear2, mMonth2, mDay2);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID_2:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener2, mHour2, mMinute2, false);
    }
    return null;
}


private Long getDateInMS(String stringDateTime) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd hh mm");
    SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd hh mm");

    String formatdate1 = simpledateformat1.format("mYear1, mMonth1, mDay1, mHour1, mMinute1");
    String formatdate2 = simpledateformat2.format("mYear12, mMonth2, mDay2, mHour2, mMinute2");

    Date startdate = simpledateformat1.parse(formatdate1);
    Date enddate = simpledateformat2.parse(formatdate2);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: show the code you tried on php side?

Comment: I programmed like this, but didn't try yet. I'm not sure if it is right.

//time_init.php
<?php
$host ="localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "admin";
$db = "shared_p";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
?>

//add_park_info.php
<?php
require "time_init.php";

$pic = $_POST["picurl"];
$owner = $_POST["owner"];
$mobile = $_POST["mobile"];
$addrs = $_POST["addrs"];
$o_time = $_POST["o_time"];
$fee = $_POST["fee"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO park_info VALUES ('$pic', '$owner', '$mobile', '$addrs', '$o_time', '$fee');";

?>

Comment: If you want to store date_time in php mysql then for your `$o_time` variable use php date() function like     `$o_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s, strtotime($_POST['o_time']))`